# Google Sheets, how to add row totals that have same values in another column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have several sales, and they have a payment type column (F) with tow options; Efectivo (Cash) or Transferencia (wire transf), there is also a corresponding sale price column (G), and cost column (H).

What I would like to do is have in another sheet a summary, one row which which will add up all the totals for Cash payments and another row with all the wire transfer payments totals.

So using the attached extract as an example there would be;
Efectivo Sale $10,490 Costo $3200 Profit $7290

Any pointers on how to do this is much appreciated. Thanks!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzZPPrAYUiE5sSGZww02hRfois-SfvOODOk4l-qGnHk/edit?usp=sharing

[extract of my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo4vn.png)

Comment: Please share a link to a sample spreadsheet with data as shown in your post image. This will allow a place to test formulas and leave them in the sheet for you. Otherwise, you are expecting the volunteers here to start by manually typing your data into another sheet themselves; and that will be a deterrent.

Comment: Thanks, here is a link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzZPPrAYUiE5sSGZww02hRfois-SfvOODOk4l-qGnHk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution 1: by using the query

`=query(Sheet1!F:I,"select F, sum(G), sum(H), sum(I) where F is not null group by F")`

[image]

solution 2: by using the sumif & arrayformula

`=ArrayFormula(sumif(Sheet1!F:F&Sheet1!G1:I1,A6:A7&B5:D5,Sheet1!G:I))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sergey, the Arrayformula worked great for me!